# Why does For work, but ForEach does not in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

We have an array of strings of numbers

```
$a = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

**foreach** loop doesn't change the type, result: [0]=>string(1) "1"

```
foreach ($a as $v) $v = (int) $v;
```

**for** loop makes ints from strings, result: [0]=>int(1)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) $a[$i] = (int) $a[$i];
```

Please, explain why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The same reason that

```
$v = $a[0];
$v = int($v);
```

doesn't change `$a`. `$v` is a copy of the array element, not a reference to it.

You can make it work using a reference variable

```
foreach ($a as &$v) {
    $v = (int)$v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Where can I read about **&$v** construction?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php